# Given a 3 vector basis, find the 4th vector to complete R^4.

Tags: linear-algebra

IF we choose the vectors [1,1,1,0]^T, [0,0,1,1]^T and [1,1,0,0]^T as proposed basis vectors for *R*^4, find the remaining vector required to complete a basis for *R*^4.

I just need to confirm that my thinking is correct....

Form a matrix A (4x4) containing the given 3 vectors and add the fourth vector (column) as [c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4]^T.  Solve for each c using Ax=0.  Is this correct?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  I'm not concerned with doing the math, I am concerned with my logic.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What do you want to accomplish that way?

Comment: @DonAntonio~A problem that has to be worked for my class.  I'm trying to use the concepts that we've learned so far to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that works (although it is a bit overkill). You can take the augmented matrix:
$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&1&c_1&0 \\
1&0&1&c_2&0 \\
1&1&0&c_3&0 \\
0&1&0&c_4&0 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
and row reduce it to an echelon form such as:
$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&1&c_1&0 \\
0&1&0&c_4&0 \\
0&0&1&c_1-c_3+c_4&0 \\
0&0&0&c_2-c_1&0 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
Notice that since the four vectors must be linearly independent, the only solution for this system is the trivial solution. Hence, there must be a pivot in every column (other than the fifth column). This can only happen if $c_2-c_1 \neq 0$. Thus, we can pick any fourth vector of the form:
$$\left[ \begin{array}{c}
c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\c_4
\end{array} \right]$$
**provided that** $\boxed{c_1 \neq c_2}$. For example, you can pick:
$$\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1\\0\\0\\0
\end{array} \right]$$

Comment: ~  that's what I got.  Just needed to see it done in that manner since that's where we are at in class.

Answer (score 2):

Just take the determinant of $A$ and ensure that it is nonzero. That will guarantee that the four vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Your vectors are

$$u_1:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;u_2:=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;u_3:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Notice that the only way to change the fourth coordinate is by multiplying $\,u_2\,$ by some scalar, and this automatically multiplies the third coordinate by the same scalar, and thus...etc. , so you can choose a vector that does **not** fulfill this restrictions, say for example

$$u_4=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: ~Is there a way to show this using matrix manipulations?  Both you and Berci came up with the same example for a fourth vector.  I need to show this with matrix manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a:=(1,1,1,0)^T,\ \ b:=(0,0,1,1)^T,\ \ c:=(1,1,0,0)^T$. Then we have
$\ (0,0,1,0)^T=c-a\ $ and $\ (0,0,0,1)^T=b-(c-a)$. From this, it could be easy to see that ${\rm span}(a,b,c)={\rm span}(c,\,c-a,\,b-(c-a))\,=\,\{(u,u,v,w)^T\,\mid\, u,v,w\in\Bbb R\}$.

For a fourth vector, you can take e.g. $(1,0,0,0)^T$.

Answer (score 1):

I am learning Linear Algebra at the moment but I hope my answer will help you.

If only three vectors are defined, they span only 3-dim. subspace in your $\mathbb{R}^4$ space. If the set of all vectors are to span the full $\mathbb{R}^4$, all 4 vectors including the one with $\textbf{c}$'s must be *linearly independent*. That occurs when any *linear combination* can always give solution different from $\textbf{0}$, that is $\textbf{Ax}\neq\textbf{0}$ for all possible $\textbf{x}$'s excluding the trivial solution $\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$.

If you take the 4th vector and you find solution such that $\textbf{Ax}=\textbf{0}$, vectors are *linearly dependent* and one of the vectors is a *linear combination* of the others. The *determinant* will then be = 0 and they will not span the full $\mathbb{R}^4$. As said, one of the tests is to calculate a *determinant*. Another way would be to transform a matrix into upper triangular by *elimination* and look for pivots. If one of the pivots is equal to 0, then again your vectors do not span the full $\mathbb{R}^4$ space because they are *linearly dependent*.

Comment: ~  Thank you!  Nice written explanation. I am currently taking a grad course in Linear Algebra, but it has been years since my undergrad course.  I'm having to relearn a lot of it.

Comment: No problem. I am glad I could help. If you need to learn more than that, there's a great Introduction to Linear Algebra by Professor Gilbert Strang in Massachusetts Institute of Technology availabel online [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&list=ECE7DDD91010BC51F8). I learned a lot from it!

Comment: ~ I saw that.  It is his book that we are working out of.  I am going to take some time and look into his tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are fine, but you can also generalize the cross product from $\mathbb{R}^3$ which takes pairs of vectors and outputs a vector, to a similar mechanism for $\mathbb{R}^4$, only it will take triples of vectors to produce a vector. What is produced will be orthogonal to the given three vectors (an advantage over other answers), and have other properties relative to the first three vectors. It is however more computationally intense than say, observing that $\langle1,0,0,0\rangle$ would do.

It goes like this: $$\vec{v}_4=\det\begin{vmatrix}\hat{i}&\hat{j}&\hat{k}&\hat{\ell}\\1&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\\1&1&0&0\end{vmatrix}$$
$$\vec{v}=\left\langle\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&0&0\end{vmatrix},-\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&0&0\end{vmatrix},\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&1&0\end{vmatrix},-\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\0&0&1\\1&1&0\end{vmatrix}\right\rangle=\langle1,-1,0,0\rangle$$

Comment: ~We discussed taking the cross product of the vectors as well.  But when providing an example in class, the prof chose the procedure that Adriano showed here.