# Find the basis of GF(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I do past papers and I stumbled upon this question in one of the papers. I know what is GF(2), but I have no idea how to find the basis from the given data.

\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}

The question asks me to find the basis of GF(2)^4 with the given 3 elements above. I tried to find information online, but could not find any examples upon GF(2). Basically, I need to find one more element, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Try $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Hint: Those three vectors all belong to the subspace of vectors with an even number of $1$s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Transpose these column vectors to row vectors, and perform row reduction in $\mathbf F_2$. It is not hard then to find a row vector which is not in the row space of the first three: you just have to check the determinant is not $0$.

Comment: Hi, I used this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415960/given-a-3-vector-basis-find-the-4th-vector-to-complete-r4?fbclid=IwAR234jeg3lJnDKTifI1Xuz1z2H5EkTpOt8G4k0XzNSS7HB_MT4axKZIHWdg and Adriano's answer. I reduced matrix to echelon form and I got 1st column = [1;0;0;0] 2nd = [ 1 1 0 0], 3rd = [ 1 1 1 0] and 4th = [c1; c1 + c2; c1+c2+c3; c1+c2+c3+c4]. Because c1+c2+c3+c4 needs to be 1 (pivot). Does it mean that one solution could be a column [ 1 0 0 0]? Would be helpful if you could confirm if I am correct.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to do the standard method to complete a set of vectors to a basis. The standard basis for $\mathrm{GF(2)}^{4}$ is
$$\left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} \right\rbrace.$$
So you set up a matrix with your three vectors, and then the standard basis, as columns:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
and then you find a basis for the column space by reducing the matrix to echelon form (over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$ and determining the pivot columns. Those columns of your original matrix will give you a basis for $\mathrm{GF}(2)^{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Unsophisticated method:

There are $16$ elements of GF$(2)^4:$

$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$

Linear combinations of your $3$ elements yield the following $8$:

$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Take an element on the first list that's not on the second list, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for answer, could you check my comment under Bernard's answer if it makes sense?

Comment: I didn't check the details, but it sounds reasonable, and the answer you got agrees with mine